# Use an object in another class

Tags: java

I want to use the object person in the Librarian_Interface class, but this call the method login() in a loop. I think there is something I don't understand with java instance and I tried to get person with a constructor or methode but in vain. Thanks !

```
public class Login_Interface {
    Person person;

    public Login_Interface() {
        
        db.initConnection();
        person = login(db, in);
        
        if (person != null)
        {
            Librarian_Interface a = new Librarian_Interface();
            a.run();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
    }

    public static Person login(DbConnection db, Scanner sc) {
        Persons.setDbConnection(db);
        Persons persons = Persons.getInstance();

        System.out.print("\nEnter your Phone Number : ");
        String phone = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.print("\nEnter your Password : ");
        String password = sc.nextLine();

        return persons.login(phone, password);
    }

}
```

```
public class Librarian_Interface {

public Librarian_Interface() {

// What I want 
// System.out.print(person); or person.getAge(); ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is pass the `person` object to the `Librarian_Interface` constructor. then you can call methods `getAge` on it, etc.

```java
public class Librarian implements Runnable {

    private final Person person;

    public Librarian(Person person) {
        this.person = person;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int age = person.age();
        // ... whatever else
    }
}
```

By the way, the convention in Java is to use upper camel case for class names, with no underscores. So it would be better to name the class `LibrarianInterface`. Also, it's probably not the best idea to call it `LibrarianInterface` if it is in fact a `class` and not an `interface`.

Since `Librarian` has a public `run` method, it's a good idea to have it implement `Runnable` so that users of the class see how it is meant to be used.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, the problem is I have already Librarian class in another package... Is it a problem if I have 2 Librarian.java but in 2 packages different ?

Comment: It is fine to have identically named classes in different packages, though it is inconvenient if they ever appear in the same context since at least one must be referred to by its fully qualified name, i.e. <package-name>.<class-name>.

Under the current naming scheme, one would expect the other `Librarian` to be defined as: `class Librarian implements LibrarianInterface`, which can't be the case since `LibrarianInterface` is not an `interface`. So if the "`Librarian`" doesn't make sense here, best to find another name descriptive of what this class does or contains.